# JQuery Get element .height() then subtract 100vh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, viewport-units

How would one subtract a 100vh from a .height() value for example
`$('#luxy').height();` the height is 5000px I want to take 100vh from the 5000px using jQuery or Javascript not CSS?

Comment: vh is a relative unit. So you would need to use css calc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) is a unit representing 1% of the **V**iewport **H**eight

[`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) is the px value of the height of the viewport

Being as both of these are targeting the [*layout* viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts#CSS), you should be fine to do:

```js
let myHeight = $('#luxy').height() - window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Cheers, also window.innerHeight(); throws "is not a function" it should be window.innerHeight; the window height never crossed my mind, my bad.

Comment: Oh, that's my bad - Sorry, I'll fix that typo